# Getting NULL communicators with MPI_Cart_create, MPICH

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I wrote this program for my homework (parallel programming), but I'm getting some errors on running.

This is the source:

```
/****************************************
 * Program:                 *
 *  ALL_TO_ALL_BROADCAST_MESH       *
 *                      *
 * Author:                  *
 *  -------------------         *
 *  -------------------         *
 ****************************************/

/*
 * Program's using MPI_Send, MPI_Recv and cartesian topology functions
 *
 * Compile using: mpicc -o all_to_all_bc all_to_all_bc.c
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

/* Number of dimensions */
#define NUMB_DIMS 2

/* Max value for the rand() function */
#define MAX_NUMB 128

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

/* Checks if square root of n can be calculated     *
 * Returns the square root on success or -1 on failure  */
int is_sqrt(int n);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int my_rank;            /* Rank of the current process          */
    int size;           /* Number of processes in the mesh      */
    int mesh_size;          /* Size of a single mesh row            */
    int my_numb;            /* Message                  */
    int *all_numbs;         /* All numbers owned by the current process */
    int numb_numbs;         /* Number of numbers in the all_numbs array */
    int left, right, up, down;  /* Neighbourghs of the process as rank numbers  */

    /* Neighbourghs as cartesian coords */
    int *my_coords, *left_coords, *right_coords, *up_coords, *down_coords;

    /* Allocate memory for cartesian coords */
    my_coords = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
    left_coords = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
    right_coords = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
    up_coords = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
    down_coords = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));

    MPI_Comm grid_comm; /* Mesh Communicator */

    int *dim_size = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));   /* Sizes of mesh dimensions     */
    int *peroids = (int *)malloc(NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));    /* True if the column wraps around  */
    int reorder;                        /* I have no idea what this does ;) */

    int i,j; /* counters */

    /* MPI initialization */
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&my_rank);

    /* Check if p^2=N */
    if (mesh_size=is_sqrt(size)<0) {
        perror("Square root of the number of processes can't be calculated!");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Configure parameters for MPI_Cart_Create() */
    for (i=0;i<NUMB_DIMS;i++) {
        dim_size[i]=mesh_size;
        peroids[i]=TRUE;
    }
    reorder=FALSE;

    /* create new communicator */
    if (MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD,NUMB_DIMS,dim_size,peroids,reorder,&grid_comm)<0) {
        perror("Unable to create new communicator!");
        MPI_Finalize();
        return -1;
    }

    /* calculate the coords and ranks */
    MPI_Cart_coords(grid_comm,my_rank,NUMB_DIMS,my_coords);

    /* !!this block is for 2D grid only!! */
        memcpy(left_coords,my_coords,NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(right_coords,my_coords,NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(up_coords,my_coords,NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(down_coords,my_coords,NUMB_DIMS*sizeof(int));

        left_coords[0]=(left_coords[0]-1)%mesh_size;
        right_coords[0]=(right_coords[0]+1)%mesh_size;
        up_coords[1]=(up_coords[1]+1)%mesh_size;
        down_coords[1]=(down_coords[1]-1)%mesh_size;

        MPI_Cart_rank(grid_comm,left_coords,&left);
        MPI_Cart_rank(grid_comm,right_coords,&right);
        MPI_Cart_rank(grid_comm,up_coords,&up);
        MPI_Cart_rank(grid_comm,down_coords,&down);
    /* !!this block is for 2D grid only!! */

    /* get a random number for this process */
    my_numb = rand()%MAX_NUMB;

    all_numbs = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    MPI_Status status;

    /****************
     * BROADCASTING *
     ****************/

    printf("I'm process (%d,%d),\nMy number is %d\n\n",my_coords[0],my_coords[1],my_numb);

    all_numbs[0]=my_numb;
    numb_numbs=1;

    /* Communication along rows */
    for (i=0;i<mesh_size-1;i++) {

        printf("I'm process (%d,%d),\nI'm sending %d to process (%d,%d)\n\n",my_coords[0],my_coords[1],my_numb,right_coords[0],right_coords[1]);
        MPI_Send(&my_numb,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,right,99,grid_comm);

        printf("I'm process (%d,%d),\nI'm recieving data from process (%d,%d)\n\n",my_coords[0],my_coords[1],left_coords[0],left_coords[1]);
        MPI_Recv(&my_numb,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,left,99,grid_comm,&status);

        all_numbs[numb_numbs]=my_numb;
        numb_numbs++;

        printf("My current numbers are:\n");
        for (j=0;j<numb_numbs;j++)
            printf("%d, ",all_numbs[j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    /* Communication along columns */
    my_numb=all_numbs[0];

    for (i=0;i<mesh_size-1;i++) {

        printf("I'm process (%d,%d),\nI'm sending %d to process (%d,%d)\n\n",my_coords[0],my_coords[1],my_numb,up_coords[0],up_coords[1]);
        MPI_Send(&my_numb,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,up,99,grid_comm);

        printf("I'm process (%d,%d),\nI'm recieving data from process (%d,%d)\n\n",my_coords[0],my_coords[1],down_coords[0],down_coords[1]);
        MPI_Recv(&my_numb,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,down,99,grid_comm,&status);

        all_numbs[numb_numbs]=my_numb;
        numb_numbs++;

        printf("My current numbers are:\n");
        for (j=0;j<numb_numbs;j++)
            printf("%d, ",all_numbs[j]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printf("I'm process %d\nBroacasting performed!\nMy numbers are:\n");
    for (i=0;i<numb_numbs;i++)
        printf("%d, ",all_numbs[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

int is_sqrt(int n) {

    double a=n;
    double b=sqrt(a);
    double c=b*b;

    int result;

    if (a==c) {
        result=(int)b;
        return result;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

And here are the errors I'm getting:

```
% mpirun -np 4 all_to_all_bc
[cli_1]: [cli_3]: aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Cart_coords: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Cart_coords(130): MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=3, maxdims=2, coords=0x6a9010) failed
MPI_Cart_coords(74).: Null communicator
aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Cart_coords: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Cart_coords(130): MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=1, maxdims=2, coords=0x6a9010) failed
MPI_Cart_coords(74).: Null communicator
[cli_0]: aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Cart_coords: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Cart_coords(130): MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=0, maxdims=2, coords=0x6a9010) failed
MPI_Cart_coords(74).: Null communicator
[cli_2]: aborting job:
Fatal error in MPI_Cart_coords: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Cart_coords(130): MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=2, maxdims=2, coords=0x6a9010) failed
MPI_Cart_coords(74).: Null communicator
rank 3 in job 18  ---host---_58157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 3: killed by signal 9 
rank 2 in job 18  ---host---_58157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 2: return code 1 
rank 1 in job 18  ---host---_58157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 1: killed by signal 9 
rank 0 in job 18  ---host---_58157   caused collective abort of all ranks
  exit status of rank 0: return code 1
```

Comment: Is everything correct in the header file #include "mpi.h"- looks like some function from that is not called correctly...

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

Looking at your error message:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Cart_coords: Invalid communicator, error stack:
MPI_Cart_coords(130): MPI_Cart_coords(MPI_COMM_NULL, rank=3, maxdims=2, coords=0x6a9010) failed
MPI_Cart_coords(74).: Null communicator
```

it looks like the communicator for `MPI_Cart_coords` is null. Scanning back, this is initialised by the call to `MPI_Cart_create` ~5 lines above.

From the `MPI_Cart_create` man page (my emphasis):

> DESCRIPTION
>
> MPI_Cart_create  returns a handle to a new communicator to which the
>   Cartesian topology information is attached. If reorder = false  then
>   the  rank  of each process in the new group is identical to its rank
>   in the old group. Otherwise, the function may reorder the  processes
>   (possibly  so  as to choose a good embedding of the virtual topology
>   onto the physical machine). **If the total size of the Cartesian  grid
>   is  smaller  than the size of the group of comm, then some processes
>   are returned MPI_COMM_NULL, in analogy to MPI_Comm_split.**  The  call
>   is  erroneous  if  it specifies a grid that is larger than the group
>   size.

Looks like this may be your issue.

Comment: But it seems in this case, that all processes are returned NULL, and size of the communicator has to be right in order to run the program - it will stop if number of processes != m^n